# class cast exception with custom gallery android

Tags: android

i'm trying to make a custom Gallery in my app. I created a class that extends Gallery but when i try to get the gallery from my xml i get a `ClassCastException`

**Here is what i'm trying to do**

```
 MyCustomGallery mcg = (MyCustomGallery )findViewById(R.id.gallery);;
 d.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images));
```

**This is my custom gallery class**

```
public class MyCustomGallery extends Gallery {

    public MyCustomGallery (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, 100, 100);

    }
}
```

**and this is my xml:**

```
<Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:spacing="20dp"
    />
```

what i'm i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared it as a plain Gallery in your xml, you need to declare it as your custom gallery.

```
<com.yourPackage.MyCustomGallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:spacing="20dp"
    />
```

Note that you must include the full package name in the declaration inside your xml or it will not work properly.

Comment: i actually had done that but i got this: `NoSuchMethodException: MyCustomGallery(Context,AttributeSet)` any ideas?

Comment: sorry for the dumb question :S it's fixed i just took the constructor it was asking for `MyCustomGallery(Context,AttributeSet)`. Problem fixed, thanks for the answer.